# Как избавиться от workbox в консоле в next js?

Tags: workbox

[image]

Подскажите, плиз, как избавиться от такого рода мусора в консоле? PWA нормально работает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сообщения появляются из-за режима разработки.

В файл `next.config.js`

```
workbox.setConfig({ debug: false });
```

или

```
module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: 'public',
      mode: 'production'
    },
 });
```

Источник: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952421/nextjs-remove-workbox-console-log-messages)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Второй вариант не подошел, но первый - помог)